GitLab CI/CD variables in appsettings.json for .NET Projects
Is there a simple way to simulate Azure DevOps Replace Token task in GitLab CI/CD?
I have the following secret (with many others) in appsettings.Testing.json that I need to replace in deploy stage:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RabbitMq": "amqp://dev-test:#{RabbitPassword}#@TST.local/dev-test"
  },

#{ ... }# is the default one for Azure DevOps Replace Token task. I don't need to use the same but can't figure out how to do it. In my CI/CD variable I already added RabbitPassword for all environments.
Tried other suggested template like ${RabbitPassword} but it's not working. What am i missing?
